# SQL Server - Is there a way to change "sa" password with a non-administrator windows account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I forgot SQL Server sa password and i don't have access to administrator account. Is there a way to rename sa accounts password so that i can have admin rights?

Comment: Usually the administrator on the (Windows) server you're running SQL Server has administrative rights.

Comment: This windows machine has multiple administrators and im using one of them which has not rights to edit the service properties too. And not even able to change sa pwd through sqlcmd.

Comment: If the user cannot change service properties then it is hardly an administrator?

Comment: But is control panel / user accounts it shows as one of the domain/administrator user account.

Comment: sql server 2012 does not make a windows administrator automatically sysadmin in the sql server, this was the case in SQL Server 2008 but not in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Installed a new instance and made it default instance which is a crooked way. And now im able to use it as a usual database server with all new sa account and password. Is there any proven better way please add as answer.